# I can't seem to get this sql query to work the way i want

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

I have a table with some ratings for books;

These are some dummy records I have created to test this query out;

```
 ID    BookID   RatersID     Rating    Date
 1     2        3            5         (date)
 2     2        4            4         (date)


SELECT `RatersID`,
COUNT(*) AS `raters`, `Rating`, COUNT(*) AS `Ratings`
FROM
`BOOKS_ratings`
GROUP BY
`BookID`
```

When I run the query I expected

```
BookID    Raters     Ratings
2         2          9
```

What I get:

```
RatersID    raters    Rating    Ratings
3           2         5         2
```

I do not understand why this is happening?
/////////////////// Above has been answered

I have got the query working but when trying to receive the information in php the numbers are duplicated

E.g Raters = 2 PHP shows 22
   Ratings = 9 PHP shows 99

```
    $getratingq = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT `RatersID`, COUNT(*) AS `Raters`, sum(Rating) AS `Ratings` FROM `BOOKS_ratings` WHERE `BookID` ='$bookid' GROUP BY `BookID` LIMIT 1") or die("Get ratings query error");
if($getrating = mysqli_fetch_array($getratingq))
{
   echo $ratings = $getrating['Ratings'];
   $raters= $getrating['Raters'];
   $rating =  $ratings/$raters;
   $stars = floor("$rating");
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use `sum()` to get the sum of Rating

```
    SELECT 
   `BookID`,
    COUNT(*) AS `raters`
    sum(Rating) as Ratings
    FROM
    `BOOKS_ratings`
    GROUP BY
    `BookID`
```

Comment: Thank you, I realised my mistake, I used the count which counted how many people rated, insted i should of used the sum